# How to convert varchar date to date type in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have column with date, that has format 'yyyy-mm-dd', I want to convert it to the date type with format 'dd/mm/yyyy'. How can I do that?

If I do `to_date(Date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`, the result is, for example: `12/06/0020`.
But I want `12/06/2020`.
So maybe, firstly I need some query, that edits all rows from `12/06/20` to `12/06/2020`? How can I do that?

Comment: **NEVER** store date values in `varchar` columns. Do you have a chance to fix that broken desing?

Comment: No I am importing it from .csv, all columns are varchar

Comment: You can import CSV files into proper, correct `date` columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name okey, but what about converting it by hand now for one column, that I need?)

Comment: You have it as `12/06/0020` or `12/06/20`

Answer (score 0):

To get the `12/06/20` as `12/06/2020`

You can use:

```
to_date(vCol, 'DD/MM/YY')
```

and here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9f021c4adbedce33656a04adb66430cd)